# How to create array of ng- models

Tags: angularjs

I am developing website using angularJs. In app i need to create dynamic select boxes having same model name. code is given below

### HTML Code

```
<tr ng-repeat="results in result">
    <td>{{results.domain}}</td>
    <td>{{results.status}}</td>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="price[$index]" class="form-control" name="price" ng-options="price.dp_id as price.title for price in results.price"> </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

### AngularJs Code

```
app.controller("Site", function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.selectedPerson = 0;
    $scope.urlName = "alankar12";
    $scope.domainExt = "";
    $scope.showresult=false;
    $scope.result = {};
    $scope.price=[];


    $scope.checkDomain = function() {   
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/domain/index.php?r=site/checkdomain',
            data:{urlName:$scope.urlName,domainExt:$scope.domainExt},
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.domainExt=data;
            $scope.result=data.records;
            $scope.showresult=true;
            //$scope.price=data.price;
            console.log(data.price);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });

    }; //end checkdomain Function

    $scope.addDomain = function() {

        console.log($scope.price);
    }
});
```

---

### json response

```
{
    "response": "successful",
    "status": "200",
    "records": [{
        "domain": ".com",
        "status": "available",
        "price": [{
            "title": "1 year@600",
            "price": "600.00"
        }, {
            "title": "2 year @1150",
            "price": "1150.00"
        }]
    }, {
        "domain": ".co.in",
        "status": "available",
        "price": [{
            "title": "1 year@700",
            "price": "700.00"
        }, {
            "title": "2 year @1350",
            "price": "1350.00"
        }]
    }, {
        "domain": ".in",
        "status": "available",
        "price": [{
            "title": "1 year@660",
            "price": "660.00"
        }, {
            "title": "2 year @1350",
            "price": "1350.00"
        }]
    }, {
        "domain": ".org",
        "status": "available",
        "price": [{
            "title": "1 year@500",
            "price": "500.00"
        }]
    }, {
        "domain": ".au.in",
        "status": "available",
        "price": [{
            "title": "1 year 600",
            "price": "600.00"
        }]
    }, {
        "domain": ".au",
        "status": "available",
        "price": [{
            "title": "1 year@500",
            "price": "500.00"
        }]
    }]
}
```

---

Here every domain name has multiple prices, issue that i am facing , i am unable to get the value of price in model.

Please anyone help me to resolve issue

Comment: Official example may be help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you need to iterate over the records, not the prices.

Something like this might work:

```
<select ng-model="myPrice" class="form-control" name="price" ng-options="record.price.dp_id as record.price.title for record in results">
  <option value="">-- choose price --</option>
</select>
```

---

**EDIT**: on a closer look, I think you will need to do pre-processing on the results list before using it, so the above may not work.  Something like this would be better:

```
var allPrices = [];
results.each(function(result) {
  result.price.each(function(price) {
    // gather all prices here
  }
}
$scope.prices = allPrices;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What i did was correct but i was doing one silly mistake that i was using dm_id in values and json response there was no dm_id. 

ng-options="record.price.dp_id as record.price.title for record in results"

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Best thing to do is to add this as an answer and accept it.